# I would like to use the result of a query in another query using PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My first query should return a single result.

```
$query="select idtechnic from technic where idname='$technic' and setname='$set' and number='$number'";
```

I would like to use the result of the above query in a second query:

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
$query1="select idtechnic, move from moves where idtechnic='$row1[0]' order by idmoves";
```

I also tried  `mysql_fetch_array($query)` and `mysql_result($query, 1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT moves.idtechnic, moves.move 
FROM moves
INNER JOIN technic
        ON technic.idtechnic=moves.idtechnic
WHERE technic.idname='$technic' 
  AND technic.setname='$set' 
  AND technic.number='$number'
ORDER BY moves.idmoves
```

Combine the two queries with a [INNER JOIN [MySQL Docs]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html).

Comment: Impressive young cularis-walker.

Comment: Don't guess, it was a good answer. Kind of magical! I will accept when the minutes allow it.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` fetches an associative array (aka hash or map). So, your `idtechnic` value reside in `$row1['idtechnic']`. But you'd better combine the queries like @cularis suggests, as it will result in faster and more readable code.